# MySQL-Why does this query use full index scan?

Tags: mysql, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I'm currently studying `DB index`.
In the MySQL `classicmodels db`, I don't know why does this query use full index scan.

```
    select salesRepEmployeeNumber, count(*) 
    from customers 
    where creditLimit > 100000
    group by salesRepEmployeeNumber;
```

**The customers table has clustered index on customerNumber and Non-clustered index on salesRepEmployeeNumber**. From what I learned, there is a `<key, key of clustered index>` in the data entry of the non-clustered tree. **Isn't the `creditLimit column` that exists in the `WHERE` clause information that can only be known by accessing the data record? If so, shouldn't MySQL query optimizer use `full table scan` not `full index scan`?**[B tree clustered index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo2uS.png) [B tree Non-clustered index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQeV0.png) [Query Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxlrt.png)

Comment: Is this a typo?  `salesRepEmployeeNumcustomersber`

Comment: Thanks. It is typo, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index defined on `(credit limit, salesRepEmployeeNumber)`, this query can be fulfilled from the index alone without touching the data pages.

Comment: @ChaeunGong: you should create the index that this answers suggests, so your query executes quickly.

Comment: @GMB: Thanks your comment. I know that. But I want to know why does the query optimizer use **full index scan** not **full table scan**?

Comment: I'm sorry. When I checked the post, the content was strange, so I modified the post. My point is why the query optimizer uses 'full index scan' when there are no indexes associated with creditLimits.

Comment: Can you provide output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers;` ?